# There's a large gap between the title and question

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

In the question screen, I'm seeing a very large gap between the title and the body of questions.
At first I thought i was because I clicked on a link from twitter, but it seems to happen with several questions even from my feed from within the app. I haven't figured out a pattern, but is seems to happen with the majority of the questions I've looked at.

[image: Screen shot of gap]

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: Galaxy S3 on Sprint.

Comment: Getting the same on an HTC One X. Android 4.2.2 and HTC Sense 5.0.

Comment: Discovered a little more. It happens whenever the title is long enough to split onto two lines. I cannot reproduce on short titles.

Comment: On short titles, if I pull down and refresh, it throws the title to two lines and adds the large gap.

Comment: Doing a dump view from eclipse shows the TextView for the title stretches vertically inside the parent LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in the next version update, 1.0.15. I say "should" because we only found one device that could reproduce it at Stack HQ and it wasn't 100% of the time, but we haven't been able to reproduce it on that device since the last change I made to that view. Let me know if it happens for you again after that version update.

Comment: Just got the update and it seems to have fixed it. Thanks.